# Django- Display calculated value in a form from other form fields

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am a beginner in Django and I have this scenario: a customer wants to know the equivalent of a sum in his local currency.

He fills a form (`ModelForm`) where he indicates the amount and the country and the program calculates the equivalent amount in local currency.

After filling the country and amount fields in the form, the new amount is correctly calculated and saved in the database, but the equivalent_amount field doesn't change in the form displayed.

My question is:

How can I update the view of the form so when the user inserts the amount and the country, the `new_amount` field is displayed automatically with its calculated value ? should I integrate a JavaScript code in it? If so, how?

Here is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import  ConversionForm
from .calculate_amount import calculate

def convert(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = ConversionForm(request.POST)
else:
    form = ConversionForm()
if form.is_valid():
    conversion = form.save(commit=False)
    conversion.local_amount=calculate(conversion.initial_amount,conversion.country)
    conversion.save()

return render(request, 'convertamount/convertform.html', {'form': form})
```

And here is my convertform.html

```
<h1>Conversion form</h1>
<form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where exactly is this error thrown? Show us the full stack trace and show us your ‘calculate’ function

Comment: I could fix the issue by deleting the inserted conversion and relaunching the server. My new problem is in the modified question above

Comment: Show us your views.py, where do you redirect after saving the form?